# Путь сохранения через WriteAllText

Tags: c#, файлы

Есть кнопка которая сохраняет ключи по разным файлам

```
File.WriteAllText("private.xml", privatekey, Encoding.UTF8);
File.WriteAllText("public.xml", publickey, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Хочу добавить окошко с выводом куда оно сохранилось с полным путем.

```
MessageBox.Show("Сохранено в файлах " + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\private.xml \n" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\public.xml", "Сохранено", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Но что то типо такого делать как по мне это не правильно? Но это все что я смог придумать, подскажите как лучше сделать?

Comment: Почему неправильно? Что именно вас смущает?

Comment: @VladD смущает эти записи `Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\имя_файла.расширение"`, я думал, что есть какой нибудь стандартный метод который возвращает путь сохраненного файла таким образом, но я ничего не нашел, либо плохо искал.

Comment: Первое что можно улучить это использовать `Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "имя_файла.расширение")` - во всяком случае это избавит Вас от слешей или обратных слешей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, подтверждение успешных действий — неправильно. Сообщение нужно выдавать в случае *ошибки*, а когда всё хорошо, отвлекать юзера нет смысла.

Затем, каталог. Лучше дать юзеру возможность выбрать каталог самостоятельно. Например, так:

```
var dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog()
{
    Description = "В какой каталог сохранять ключи?",
    RootFolder = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
    ShowNewFolderButton = true;
};

var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
if (result != DialogResult.OK)
    return; // юзер не хочет сохранять, ну и не надо

try
{
    var folder = dlg.SelectedPath;
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(folder, "private.xml"), privatekey, Encoding.UTF8);
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(folder, "public.xml"), publickey, Encoding.UTF8);
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Каталог не найден", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
catch (IOException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка ввода-вывода (сбойный диск?)",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Нет доступа, такой файл уже есть или недостаточно прав?",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
catch (SecurityException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Недостаточно прав для сохранения",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, я хотел вывести окно т.к не давал выбор куда сохранять если делать через savefiledialog

Comment: @PavelFedorov: Показывать юзеру подтверждение успешно выполненной операции не нужно. Зачем юзеру message box? Чтобы он запомнил каталог или записал на бумажке, и потом искал его на диске? Очень удобно. Если хотите помочь юзеру, откройте лучше ему нужный каталог в проводнике.

Comment: Согласен, но я еще только изучаю c#, и не хотел возится с savefiledialog т.к. два файла нужно по очереди сохранить. А почему вы написали не через savefiledialog? Просто фильтр сделать на xml

Comment: @PavelFedorov: Потому что `SaveFileDialog` задаёт путь для одного файла, а юзеру-то надо сохранить несколько.

Comment: @PavelFedorov: Плюс нехорошо требовать у юзера задавать самому имя.

Comment: попробовал, кнопка работает но я не могу понять почему это само диалоговое окно не возникает, я только написал вот так `var folder = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;` Оно сохраняет по кнопке так, но не возникает окно этого FolderBrowserDialog

Comment: @PavelFedorov: А вы не забыли вызвать `ShowDialog()`?

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрался.